# Serilog is not logging logs from Program.cs

Tags: .net-6.0, serilog, serilog-sinks-file, microsoft.extensions.logging

I've updated my .NET 5 application to .NET 6 and encountered a logging issue. In Program.cs  Everything above the line `var app = builder.Build();` is being logged to the console, while anything below that line isn't getting logged to either the console or the text file. I suspect this is because the configuration from `appsettings.json` takes effect after calling `Build()`, and in appsettings.json the default log level is set to `Error`. Although I've set an override for `"DefaultNameSpace.Program":"Information"` in appsettings.json, it doesn't seem to be working for the logs in Program.cs.

The `DefaultNameSpace` is the namespace that is set in project settings.

[image]

In . NET 6, you no longer need to write out the Program class and Main method. What would be the correct namespace for Program class?

**program.cs**

```
// The initial "bootstrap" logger is able to log errors during start-up. It's completely replaced by the
// logger configured in `UseSerilog()` below, once configuration and dependency-injection have both been
// set up successfully.
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()    
    .WriteTo.Console()
    .CreateBootstrapLogger();

Log.Information("Starting up!");

try
{
    var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
    builder.Host.UseSerilog((context, services, configuration) => configuration
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(context.Configuration));

    builder.WebHost.UseUrls("http://*:40004");    

    Log.Information("Building application.");

    // Information logs above this line are logged
    var app = builder.Build();

    // Information logs below are not getting logged        
    Log.Information("Running application");

    app.Run();

    Log.Information("Application Started");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Fatal(ex, "An unhandled exception occurred during bootstrapping");
}
finally
{
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

**appsettings.json**

```
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console","Serilog.Sinks.File" ],
  "MinimumLevel": {
    "Default": "Error",
    "Override": {
      "Microsoft": "Warning",        
      "MyNameSpace.Program": "Information"
    }
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "Console"
    },
    {
      "Name": "File",
      "Args": {
        "path": "C:\\Logs\\UI.txt",
        "fileSizeLimitBytes": "10485760",
        "rollingInterval": "Day",
        "rollOnFileSizeLimit": true
      }
    }
  ]
},
```